# How can I turn off margin notes in a LaTeX article?

Tags: margins

I want to use LaTeX for typesetting astrology charts, and won't need to use any margin notes. What's the best way to disable margin notes so I can have the space for wheel charts?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to reduce the margins on the page, freeing up more space the astrology chart? If so, I suggest you take a look at http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=changemargin and the links therein.

Comment: @Willie: yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: And you're sure your *readers* won't be needing that space for notes?

Comment: @SamB: In none of my astrology readings I've done has the client ever taken notes. They have complained, however, about the charts being too small to read.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I had sorta assumed you were doing something more academic in nature with the charts ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily set the margins to a constant amount using the [geometry](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package, e.g.:

`\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.25in,right=1.25in]{geometry}`

See the documentation for more info.

Answer (score 6):

```
\usepackage[nomarginpar, margin=.5in]{geometry}
```

Or without a package:

```
\marginparwidth 0pt
\marginparsep 0pt
\oddsidemargin \dimexpr .5in -1in
\textwidth \dimexpr \pdfpagewidth -2\oddsidemargin -2in
```

1. Remove margin notes
2. Set left margin to .5in

   This step is tricky because *oddsidemargin* is not the length from the left
   edge, but the length from 1 inch from the left edge. So when you set it you
   have to subtract that inch.
3. Increase body width

   Again, normally the body would be `pagewidth - 2 * margin`, but we need to
   account for the inch offset on both sides.